# Rewrite WordPress URL with custom paramater

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a site that has an image slide show. When changing slides I change the URL using history and append a parameter too. What I need to do is make the URL tidier.

The URL can be saved for later and I pull the data from the current structure fine.

Example URL:

```
http://domain.com/projects/single-landscape/?layout_id=1
```

The projects is a post type and the single-landscape is a post in that post type.

The ?layout_id is simply something I add myself with JS so nothing to do with WordPress itself.

All i'm looking to do is be able enter:

```
http://domain.com/projects/single-landscape/1
http://domain.com/projects/single-landscape/2
http://domain.com/projects/single-landscape/3
```

And carry on the same as I am now pulling out that number as the layout id. The projects part is fixed as its the only post type im using in this case and but the 'single-project' can change.

Looking through the docs doesn't seem to help for me, just need a simple push in the right direction with an example and i'm sure ill then understand.

Comment: Have you looked at [Class Reference/WP Rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)?

Comment: add a .htaccess rewrite condition rule many other posts about how to write the correct regex for that

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, [reference here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(projects/[^/]+/)(\d+)$ $1?layout_id=$2
```

Put it in your root .htaccess file.